Using window.matchMedia() to handle the different screen sizes and jQuery to update the DOM
When I am using multiple CSS classes on JS, window.onresize isn't working for me.
Tried different solutions on the web to solve but none worked for me.
My codes:
JS:
window.onresize = function(event) {
    console.log(event);
  var mq = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)');

  if (mq.matches) {
    $('.front-screen .overlay .container .seat .front-row .seats .legend').addClass('front-screen-mw768 overlay-mw768 container-mw768 seat-mw768 front-row-mw768 seats-mw768 legend-mw768')
  } else {
    $('.front-screen .overlay .container .seat .front-row .seats .legend').removeClass('front-screen-mw768 overlay-mw768 container-mw768 seat-mw768 front-row-mw768 seats-mw768 legend-mw768');
  }
};

function appendSeats(seats, rowType) {
  const row = document.querySelector(`.${rowType}`);
  for (let i = 1; i <= seats; i++) {
    const seat = document.createElement("div");
    seat.classList.add("seat");
    row.appendChild(seat);
  }
}

function selectSeats() {
  const seat = document.querySelectorAll(".seat");
  seat.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("click", () => {
      item.classList.toggle("selected");
    });
  });
}

function markRandomSeats(SEAT_RESERVED) {
  const totalSeats = document.querySelectorAll(".seat");
  const reservedSeats = getRandomSeats(totalSeats, SEAT_RESERVED);
  reservedSeats.forEach((seat) => {
    seat.classList.add("reserved");
  });
}

function getRandomSeats(seats, count) {
  const shuffledSeats = Array.from(seats).sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
  return shuffledSeats.slice(0, count);
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const SEAT_RESERVED = 10;
  appendSeats(12, "first-front-row");
  appendSeats(14, "second-front-row");
  appendSeats(96, "middle-row");
  appendSeats(14, "second-last-row");
  appendSeats(12, "first-last-row");
  selectSeats();
  markRandomSeats(SEAT_RESERVED);
});

CSS:
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

body {
  background-color: #121212;
  color: white;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  border: 4px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 550px;
  width: 650px;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.front-screen {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 580px;
}

.screen {
  background-color: white;
  width: calc(100% - 8.5rem);
  height: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  clip-path: polygon(4.2rem 0%, 32.1rem 0%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.seats{
    flex: 1;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 1rem;
}
.front-row{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 1rem;
}

.middle-row{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
    gap: 1rem;
}

.seat{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.seat.reserved{
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

.legend{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 2rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.legend > div{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    gap: 0.5rem;
}

.legend .seat{
    pointer-events: none;
}

.selected{
    background-color: #9195f8;
}

.reserved{
    background-color: red;
}

/* 768 breakpoint */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .front-screen-mw768 {
    width: 26rem;
  }
  
  .overlay-mw768 {
    height: 2rem;
    clip-path: polygon(4.2rem 0%, 21.1rem 0%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  }
  
  .container-mw768 {
    border: none;
    border-radius: unset;
    height: 34rem;
    width: 39rem;
  }
  
  .seat-mw768 {
    height: 1rem;
    width: 1rem;
  }
  
  .front-row-mw768 {
    gap: 1rem;
  }
  
  .seats-mw768 {
     flex: 0;
  }

  .legend-mw768 {    
    margin: 3rem auto;
  }

}

@media (max-width: 540px) {
  .front-screen {
    width: 26rem;
  }

  .overlay {
    height: 2rem;
    clip-path: polygon(4.2rem 0%, 21.1rem 0%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  }

  .container {
    border: none;
    border-radius: unset;
    height: 34rem;
    width: 39rem;
  }

  .seat {
    height: 1rem;
    width: 1rem;
  }

  .front-row {
    gap: 5px;
  }

  .middle-row {
    gap: 5px;
  }


  .legend {    
    margin: 3rem auto;
  }
}

HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 width=%22256%22 height=%22256%22 viewBox=%220 0 100 100%22><rect width=%22100%22 height=%22100%22 rx=%2250%22 fill=%22%230058ff%22></rect><path fill=%22%23fff%22 d=%22M72.15 21.33L72.15 21.33Q74.49 22.50 74.90 25.02Q75.30 27.54 73.59 29.61L73.59 29.61Q72.42 31.23 70.58 31.41Q68.73 31.59 66.84 30.69L66.84 30.69Q64.68 29.70 62.30 29.16Q59.91 28.62 57.30 28.62L57.30 28.62Q52.44 28.62 48.62 30.15Q44.79 31.68 42.09 34.52Q39.39 37.35 38.00 41.22Q36.60 45.09 36.60 49.77L36.60 49.77Q36.60 55.26 38.18 59.31Q39.75 63.36 42.54 66.06Q45.33 68.76 49.11 70.07Q52.89 71.37 57.30 71.37L57.30 71.37Q59.73 71.37 62.16 70.92Q64.59 70.47 66.84 69.30L66.84 69.30Q68.73 68.40 70.58 68.67Q72.42 68.94 73.68 70.56L73.68 70.56Q75.48 72.81 74.99 75.20Q74.49 77.58 72.24 78.66L72.24 78.66Q69.90 79.83 67.43 80.60Q64.95 81.36 62.43 81.77Q59.91 82.17 57.30 82.17L57.30 82.17Q50.82 82.17 45.02 80.10Q39.21 78.03 34.67 73.98Q30.12 69.93 27.51 63.86Q24.90 57.78 24.90 49.77L24.90 49.77Q24.90 42.84 27.29 36.99Q29.67 31.14 34.04 26.87Q38.40 22.59 44.34 20.21Q50.28 17.82 57.30 17.82L57.30 17.82Q61.26 17.82 65.04 18.72Q68.82 19.62 72.15 21.33Z%22></path></svg>" />
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv=“Pragma” content=”no-cache”>
<meta http-equiv=“Expires” content=”-1″>
<meta http-equiv=“CACHE-CONTROL” content=”NO-CACHE”>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<!-- CSS Stylesheets -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css">
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Google Fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,100italic,200,200italic,300,300italic,regular,italic,500,500italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic,900,900italic" rel="stylesheet">
    
<title>Responsive-seat-selector-UI-V2</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="front-screen">
            <div class="screen"></div>
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="seats">
            <div class="front-row first-front-row">
            </div>
            <div class="front-row second-front-row"></div>
            <div class="middle-row"></div>
            <div class="front-row second-last-row"></div>
            <div class="front-row first-last-row"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="legend">
            <div>
                <div class="seat available"></div>
                <span>Available</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="seat selected"></div>
                <span>Selected</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="seat reserved"></div>
                <span>Reserved</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<!-- Our codes -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0pUGZvbkm6XF6gxjEnlmuGrJXVbNuzT9qBBavbLwCsOGabYfZo0T0to5eqruptLy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

</html>

Now, how can we use window.matchMedia() to handle the different screen sizes and jQuery to update the DOM?
Can anyone help me with examples?

"Not working" is way to vague . Do you get an error in your console. Does the function run at all, ...

@GertB. I don't get any error in my console. The function runs only for a single CSS class.

Does the console.log appear?

Your selector won't find anything as you're searching for .legend nested within .front-screen within .overlay ... etc. You need to separate classnames by a comma to select all classes individually $('.front-screen, .overlay, .container, .seat, .front-row, .seats .legend'). However, addClass() won't assign new class names by matching each array item (so .front-screen`` won't  get front-screenmw768). Instead you could add a generic class like mw768that could be targeted in CSS like so.legend.mw768`. Frankly, your approach appears quite complicated and may become hard to maintain

@GertB. Yes, "Event {isTrusted: true, delegateTarget: Window, type: 'resize', target: Window, currentTarget: Window, …}
"

@herrstrietzel Can you please give some demos or examples that match my approach?
